# Rails 4: Import CSV and edit with AJAX before submission

Tags: ajax, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a CSV that I am directly importing using:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: @weigh_in_cols) do |row|
    hashed_row = row.to_hash.except!(nil)
...
```

One column in the CSV is `scale_id` and my import function attempts to find a `Client` with the corresponding `scale_id`:

```
client = Client.find_by(scale_id: hashed_row["scale_id"])
```

and if no client exists, I'd like to be given the ability to select the proper `client` from a list of `clients`.

**Is there a way to edit the CSV while importing such that after selecting the correct `client`, I can update the CSV with the proper `scale_id`?**

(The method for selecting the user is outside the scope of the question, I am more concerned with editing the CSV while importing)

Answer (score 1):

I believe a better approach is to make a new CSV file, not modifying the existing one.
When you iterate through the rows and columns of the CSV file, make a hash that stores the row index and the named column with the new value. After the process of reading the entire file is done, you will have a map of where you need to change the original file.
Then you create another one modifying the values in the positions you have previous saved.

Comment: Thats a great idea, don't know why I didnt think of that